# angularJS templating, proper use of directives or alternatives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

In my app, I have a main controller as usual.
Let's say it's a webshop with different products and I want to compare X products. The HTML to display 1 product, is re-usable for all other products that get compared.

This means this HTML should be in a template (this is the point where I would've used Handlebars in a jQuery driven app).

I created a partial called `itemDetails.php`.

This template needs to get inserted into my view - let's say: - two times with different data (normally that'd be the model but in Angular that's the scope?).

So I tried it with two directives like this:

JavaScript

```
myApp.directive('activeItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.php'
    };
});

myApp.directive('activeCompareItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.php'
    };
});
```

Inside the main View

```
<div class="product left" active-item>{{item.name}}</div>
<div class="product right" active-compare-item>{{item.name}}</div>
```

This - of course - doesn't work as both products will have the same data from the parent scope.
So I tried to isolate the scope:

```
myApp.directive('activeItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '@itemOne'
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.php'
    };
});

myApp.directive('activeCompareItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '@itemTwo'
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.php'
    };
});
```

But that doesn't work either because apparently I can use "item" only as an HTML attribute now, not as an expression `{{item.name}}`.

Are directives even the right approach to templating? If yes, how can I pass data from the parent scope to a directive, keep them both in sync and update/re-render the directive when the objects get changed?

It seems odd to me that I have to create new directives for each time I want to use the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive declaration:

```
myApp.directive('activeItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=data' //use "data" attribute to add the different data into the directive.
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.php'
    };
});
```

To use it with different data

```
<div class="product left" active-item data="itemOne">{{item.name}}</div>
<div class="product right" active-item data="itemTwo">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: holy bananas awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I guess that is what you need. Hope it helps.